Loading ETag property when retrieve items as a stream
I am trying to read the SharePoint list contents using RenderListDataAsStream as below:
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetList(@listUrl)/RenderListDataAsStream?@listUrl=%27%2Fsites%2Fteam-a%2Flists%2FList%27
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata"
Content-Type: "application/json;odata=nometadata"

{
  "parameters": {
    "AddRequiredFields": "true",
    "DatesInUtc": "true",
    "RenderOptions": 17
  }
}

RenderListDataAsStream body parameters are set as below:
Parameters = new StreamDataRequest.StreamDataParameters
{
    DatesInUtc = true,
    ViewXml = "<View DefaultView='TRUE' Url='URL'>
                  <ViewFields>
                     <FieldRef Name='Title'/>                
                     <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
                     ....
                   </ViewFields>
               </View>",
    AddRequiredFields = true,
    Paging = pagingToken
}

I am trying to read the ETag property for the files I am loading using the request above and when I add <FieldRef Name='ETag' /> or <FieldRef Name='.etag' />, the property is not populated.
Using ctx.Web.GetFileById(); to load the file and read the ETag, is not efficient as it requires a loop over the loaded files and affects the performance.
I am trying to find out if I can load the ETag property in the ViewXML as a part of my CAML query.
The SharePoint is using the same API call to load its list information and in the response, there is ".etag" property that I am interested in:


As far as I know, unfortunately the ETag property isn’t made available directly in the list data retrieval. You have to go file by file.
I hope another answer proves me wrong :) But if not, here are some wild ideas:
What exactly do you need eTag for all the files at once for? Version control?  Can you use another property?
How often do you need to check it? How rapid are the changes you expect? Are you trying not to overwrite an archived file or something twenty users are working on daily? Can you map it to a custom property / save it somewhere else where you can bulk-retrieve it?
What if you add <FieldRef Name='.ctag' /> or <FieldRef Name='owshiddenversion' />  <FieldRef Name='.fileType' /> <FieldRef Name='.hasPdf' />  ?  Are they all populated? Do you see any rule there?

Thanks for your comment. Adding  or other tags won't change anything and I would get the properties as before. Our application uses eTag to check if the file has been updated. I know there are other ways to check this, but for the sake of consistency, we are interested in checking it this way. In other places, we get the ETag property from the context when we load the list items directly.

Since UniqueId and DocConcurrencyNumber are returned as every list item properties for files, the eTag can be generated following the format below:
"{UniqueId},DocConcurrencyNumber"

Since DocDoncurrencyNumber increases after every change made on the file, it can be used to trace file changes.
